# load asp page without refreshing treeview in master page

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, master-pages

how can i load aspx page without refreshing treeview from master page? now i have master page with treeview when i click on leaf it refresh the whole page not only the content place holder. please tell me how can i do.

I'm using asp.net

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can place content into UpdatePanel and make treeview the trigger

Comment: thank you for ur answer i used update panel before for button control but i don't now how to use for treeview please can you explain more. thank you

Comment: Just add UpdatePanel inside of content control, here's reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb398864(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: i used web.stemap and linked to masterpage using SiteMapDataSource

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an update panel:

[msnd overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386573%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)